# In kleptocats, what is the mighty alien race that the collectible refers to?

Tags: android, google-play-games, kleptocats

Not sure if this goes here, but I guess I'll find out :)

So I've been playing this game and I've had some good fun with the references (Harry, the cat who lived, triforce, gotta collect them all...) and even some I didn't know I found online... This one however...

[image: Inventory description]
[image: Close and clean]
I first thought it was tal'darim, then looked it up, and I don't think it is, even the shape isn't close to it...

So what is it? A real reference or have I been trolled by the devs?

Answer (score 4):

That symbol is the Irken Army logo from Invader Zim. As seen here.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Irken Empire symbol from Invader Zim